# Consul shows script is a invalid config key

Tags: consul

I am trying to run a shell script to do the health check using consul. I am able to do the HTTP checks but when I try the script its throwing error. ( maybe some silly mistake )

**Config File**

```
{
 "services": [
   {
     "name": "test",
     "checks": [
         {
           "script": "./test.sh",
           "interval": "15s"
         }
       ]
     }
   ] 
}
```

**Run**

```
./consul agent -enable-script-checks=true -ui -dev -config-dir=.
```

**Output**

```
==> Error parsing web.json: 1 error(s) occurred:

* invalid config key services[0].checks[0].script
```

Answer (score 0):

change your configure variable,change “script” to “args”.

for example:

```json
"args": [
    "/usr/local/bin/check_mem.py",
    "-limit",
    "256MB"
],
```

it should solve your problem